# How to shift one element of an <li> list to the right

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered linked list. I'm trying to shift one of the items in the navigation all the way to the right (Order) as if it had `text-align: right;`. I tried using `float: right;` and `text-align: right;`, but none of them seemed to work. If I set the `margin-left` to a really high number (such as 100px) it does shift to the right, but if I resize my window then I can't see it anymore or it's not on the right side of the page. Here is the HTML:

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
}

.navigation-links-no-style a {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  margin: 15px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

.navigation-links li {
  padding-top: 1.3em;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
  background: white;
  padding-left: 5em;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 14pt;
}

.order {
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
  background: #1419e2;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a class="glacier-hills" href="glacier_hills.html">
    <img src="Images/Glacier-Hills-Logo.svg" alt="" width="182" height="90">
  </a>
  <ul class="navigation-links">
    <div class="navigation-links-no-style">
      <li>
        <a class="menu" href="menu.html">Menu</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="location" href="location.html">Hours and Location</a>
      </li>
    </div>
    <li>
      <a class="order" href="order.html">Order</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're looking to move your `.order` element, you'll want to apply the `float: right` rule to the *parent* (`<li>`) element. I've added a class to this, `.order-container`, to make this easier to achieve in the following example.

Note also that once you float to the right, it will be off the screen by default.  You'll want to set a negative `margin-right` to circumvent this. I've gone with `margin-right: -10em` in the following, to match the offset from the image on the left.

Ultimately, you may wish to consider using a framework to achieve responsive design, ensuring that the offset is correct *regardless* of screen size.

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
}

.navigation-links-no-style a {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  margin: 15px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

.navigation-links li {
  padding-top: 1.3em;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
  background: white;
  padding-left: 5em;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 14pt;
}

.order {
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
  background: #1419e2;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  float: right;
}

.order-container {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10em;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a class="glacier-hills" href="glacier_hills.html">
    <img src="Images/Glacier-Hills-Logo.svg" alt="" width="182" height="90">
  </a>
  <ul class="navigation-links">
    <div class="navigation-links-no-style">
      <li>
        <a class="menu" href="menu.html">Menu</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="location" href="location.html">Hours and Location</a>
      </li>
    </div>
    <li class="order-container">
      <a class="order" href="order.html">Order</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[MDN still advises that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul) `<div>` is not a valid child of `<ul>`. Furthermore `float` adds a whole heap of side effects by removing the items from the natural flow of the document. To modernize this we can make use of `display:flex`

```css
/*Normalise body*/
body {
  margin:0;
}

/*Set flex on the nabar top position logo and links*/
.navbar {
  display: flex;
}

/*Ad a maring to the logo link*/
.navbar > a:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 5em;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
}

.navigation-links-no-style a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  /*Ad flex to the nav link element*/
  display: flex;
  /*Vertically center the links*/
  align-items:center;
}

/*Push the last element right but give it a little margin to the right*/
.navbar ul>li:last-of-type {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right:1em;
}

.navigation-links li {
  padding-top: 1.3em;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
  background: white;
}

.navbar a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 14pt;
}

.order {
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
  background: #1419e2;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a class="glacier-hills" href="glacier_hills.html">
    <img src="Images/Glacier-Hills-Logo.svg" alt="" width="182" height="90">
  </a>
  <ul class="navigation-links">
    <li>
      <a class="menu" href="menu.html">Menu</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="location" href="location.html">Hours and Location</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="order" href="order.html">Order</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use media queries for making navbar responsive.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
}
.div-links {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 70%;
}
.nav-links {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
  align-items: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.nav-links li {
  padding: 2rem;
}
.nav-items {
  width: 30%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.order {
  overflow: hidden;

  color: #ffffff !important;
  background: #1419e2;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.8rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
      <a href="glacier_hills.html">
        <img
          src="Images/Glacier-Hills-Logo.svg"
          alt=""
          width="182"
          height="90"
        />
      </a>
      <div class="div-links">
        <ul class="nav-links">
          <div class="nav-items">
            <li>
              <a class="menu" href="menu.html">Menu</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="location" href="location.html">Hours and Location</a>
            </li>
          </div>

          <li class="btn">
            <a class="order" href="order.html">Order</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```